# Will I lose my iCloud photos after losing and locking my iPhone 6s

Tags: iphone

I've lost my iPhone 6s.  I locked it via iCloud but haven't erased the data yet. In the meantime, I want to make sure my photos are safe.

If I ultimately have to erase the phone, do I need to do anything to protect and preserve my access to the photos saved in iCloud?

Comment: You shouldn't.  If you erase the phone, it no longer has a connection to iCloud.  But you  are of course backing up your photos, right?

Answer (score 2):

Any photos that are visible on iCloud.com (Photos screen) when you initiate the remote erase will **remain available**.